# Merge state objects in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

My state consists of settings selected by a user to view charts in the application. Each time a user logs in I get their respective settings from the database. I also have an initial state defined in my reducer. What is the best way to merge the settings I received from the database into my redux state? I have seen examples of using spread operator, Immer etc. but I don't quite get how to "merge" two state objects here.

One complication here is that there could be new settings that might not exist in the database so they need to be defaulted. Hence, I need to merge the initial state with the settings I get from  the DB.

**Initial State**

```
const initialState = {
    "1-0": {
        "view": "Snapshot",
        "bucket": "3_7",
        "group" : "Ratings",
        "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
        "unit"  : null,
        "min"   : 0,
        "max"   : 1000,
        "Ratings": ["A-Index", "A-Non-Index", "BBB-Index", "BBB-Non-Index"],
        "Sectors": ["Financials-Index", "Energy-Index", "Information Technology-Index"],
        "Clusters": ["0-Index", "2-Index", "2-Non-Index", "6-Index"],
        "Signals": ["0-Index", "0-Non-Index", "1-Index", "1-Non-Index", "8-Index", "8-Non-Index", "9-Index", "9-Non-Index"]
    },
    "1-1": {
        "view": "Snapshot",
        "bucket": "3_7",
        "group" : "Sectors",
        "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
        "unit"  : null,
        "min"   : 0,
        "max"   : 1000,
        "Ratings": ["A-Index", "A-Non-Index", "BBB-Index", "BBB-Non-Index"],
        "Sectors": ["Financials-Index", "Energy-Index", "Information Technology-Index"],
        "Clusters": ["0-Index", "2-Index", "2-Non-Index", "6-Index"],
        "Signals": ["0-Index", "0-Non-Index", "1-Index", "1-Non-Index", "8-Index", "8-Non-Index", "9-Index", "9-Non-Index"]
    },
    "1-2": {
        "view": "Snapshot",
        "bucket": "3_7",
        "group" : "Clusters",
        "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
        "unit"  : null,
        "min"   : 0,
        "max"   : 1000,
        "Ratings": ["A-Index", "A-Non-Index", "BBB-Index", "BBB-Non-Index"],
        "Sectors": ["Financials-Index", "Energy-Index", "Information Technology-Index"],
        "Clusters": ["0-Index", "2-Index", "2-Non-Index", "6-Index"],
        "Signals": ["0-Index", "0-Non-Index", "1-Index", "1-Non-Index", "8-Index", "8-Non-Index", "9-Index", "9-Non-Index"]
    },
    "1-3": {
        "view": "Snapshot",
        "bucket": "3_7",
        "group" : "Signals",
        "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
        "unit"  : null,
        "min"   : 0,
        "max"   : 1000,
        "Ratings": ["A-Index", "A-Non-Index", "BBB-Index", "BBB-Non-Index"],
        "Sectors": ["Financials-Index", "Energy-Index", "Information Technology-Index"],
        "Clusters": ["0-Index", "2-Index", "2-Non-Index", "6-Index"],
        "Signals": ["0-Index", "0-Non-Index", "1-Index", "1-Non-Index", "8-Index", "8-Non-Index", "9-Index", "9-Non-Index"]
    },
    "Total Inquiry Count" : {
        "unit": null,
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 1000
    },
    "Total Inquiry Volume" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 1000000000
    },
    "Quoted Inquiry Count" : {
        "unit": null,
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 1000
    },
    "Quoted Inquiry Volume" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 1000000000
    },
    "Transaction Count" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 50
    },
    "Transaction Volume Gross" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 5000000
    },
    "Transaction Volume Net" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : -2000000,
        "max" : 2000000
    }
}
```

**State loaded from Database**

```
{
  "1-0": {
    "view": "Series",
    "bucket": "3_7",
    "group": "Ratings",
    "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
    "unit": null,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000,
    "Ratings": [
      "BBB-Index",
      "A-Non-Index",
      "AA-Non-Index",
      "AA-Index",
      "A-Index",
      "AAA-Index",
      "AAA-Non-Index"
    ],
    "Sectors": [
      "Financials-Index",
      "Energy-Index",
      "Information Technology-Index"
    ],
    "Clusters": [
      "0-Index",
      "2-Index",
      "2-Non-Index",
      "6-Index"
    ],
    "Signals": [
      "0-Index",
      "0-Non-Index",
      "1-Index",
      "1-Non-Index",
      "8-Index",
      "8-Non-Index",
      "9-Index",
      "9-Non-Index"
    ]
  },
  "1-1": {
    "view": "Series",
    "bucket": "3_7",
    "group": "Ratings",
    "metric": "Total Inquiry Volume",
    "unit": "$",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000000000,
    "Ratings": [
      "BB-Index",
      "BB-Non-Index"
    ],
    "Sectors": [
      "Financials-Index",
      "Energy-Index",
      "Information Technology-Index"
    ],
    "Clusters": [
      "0-Index",
      "2-Index",
      "2-Non-Index",
      "6-Index"
    ],
    "Signals": [
      "0-Index",
      "0-Non-Index",
      "1-Index",
      "1-Non-Index",
      "8-Index",
      "8-Non-Index",
      "9-Index",
      "9-Non-Index"
    ]
  },
  "1-2": {
    "view": "Snapshot",
    "bucket": "3_7",
    "group": "Clusters",
    "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
    "unit": null,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000,
    "Ratings": [
      "A-Index",
      "A-Non-Index",
      "BBB-Index",
      "BBB-Non-Index"
    ],
    "Sectors": [
      "Financials-Index",
      "Energy-Index",
      "Information Technology-Index"
    ],
    "Clusters": [
      "0-Index",
      "2-Index",
      "2-Non-Index",
      "6-Index"
    ],
    "Signals": [
      "0-Index",
      "0-Non-Index",
      "1-Index",
      "1-Non-Index",
      "8-Index",
      "8-Non-Index",
      "9-Index",
      "9-Non-Index"
    ]
  },
  "1-3": {
    "view": "Snapshot",
    "bucket": "3_7",
    "group": "Signals",
    "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
    "unit": null,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000,
    "Ratings": [
      "A-Index",
      "A-Non-Index",
      "BBB-Index",
      "BBB-Non-Index"
    ],
    "Sectors": [
      "Financials-Index",
      "Energy-Index",
      "Information Technology-Index"
    ],
    "Clusters": [
      "0-Index",
      "2-Index",
      "2-Non-Index",
      "6-Index"
    ],
    "Signals": [
      "0-Index",
      "0-Non-Index",
      "1-Index",
      "1-Non-Index",
      "8-Index",
      "8-Non-Index",
      "9-Index",
      "9-Non-Index"
    ]
  },
  "Total Inquiry Count": {
    "unit": null,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000
  },
  "Total Inquiry Volume": {
    "unit": "$",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000000000
  },
  "Transaction Count": {
    "unit": "$",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 50
  },
  "Transaction Volume Gross": {
    "unit": "$",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 5000000
  },
  "Transaction Volume Net": {
    "unit": "$",
    "min": -1000000,
    "max": 1000000
  }
}
```

**Current Incorrect Implementation**

```
export function panels(state=initialState, action={}) {
    switch(action.type) {
case SET_VIEW:
    const newViewState = {
        ...state,
        [action.key] : {
            ...state[action.key],
            view: action.payload
        }
    };
    return newViewState;
case SET_BUCKET:
    const newBucketState = {
        ...state,
        [action.key] : {
            ...state[action.key],
            bucket: action.payload
        }
    };
    return newBucketState;
case SET_GROUP:
    const newGroupState = {
        ...state,
        [action.key] : {
            ...state[action.key],
            group: action.payload
        }
    };
    return newGroupState;
case SET_METRIC:
    const newMetricState = {
        ...state,
        [action.key] : {
            ...state[action.key],
            metric: action.payload,
            unit: state[action.payload]['unit'],
            min: state[action.payload]['min'],
            max: state[action.payload]['max']
        }
    };
    return newMetricState;
 case SETTINGS_LOADED:
    if(!action.payload || Object.keys(action.payload).length === 0) {
      return initialState;
    }
    return action.payload;
 default:
    return state;
}
```

**Desired Output**

```
{
"1-0": {
    "view": "Series",
    "bucket": "3_7",
    "group": "Ratings",
    "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
    "unit": null,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000,
    "Ratings": [
      "BBB-Index",
      "A-Non-Index",
      "AA-Non-Index",
      "AA-Index",
      "A-Index",
      "AAA-Index",
      "AAA-Non-Index"
    ],
    "Sectors": [
      "Financials-Index",
      "Energy-Index",
      "Information Technology-Index"
    ],
    "Clusters": [
      "0-Index",
      "2-Index",
      "2-Non-Index",
      "6-Index"
    ],
    "Signals": [
      "0-Index",
      "0-Non-Index",
      "1-Index",
      "1-Non-Index",
      "8-Index",
      "8-Non-Index",
      "9-Index",
      "9-Non-Index"
    ]
  },
  "1-1": {
    "view": "Series",
    "bucket": "3_7",
    "group": "Ratings",
    "metric": "Total Inquiry Volume",
    "unit": "$",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000000000,
    "Ratings": [
      "BB-Index",
      "BB-Non-Index"
    ],
    "Sectors": [
      "Financials-Index",
      "Energy-Index",
      "Information Technology-Index"
    ],
    "Clusters": [
      "0-Index",
      "2-Index",
      "2-Non-Index",
      "6-Index"
    ],
    "Signals": [
      "0-Index",
      "0-Non-Index",
      "1-Index",
      "1-Non-Index",
      "8-Index",
      "8-Non-Index",
      "9-Index",
      "9-Non-Index"
    ]
  },
  "1-2": {
    "view": "Snapshot",
    "bucket": "3_7",
    "group": "Clusters",
    "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
    "unit": null,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000,
    "Ratings": [
      "A-Index",
      "A-Non-Index",
      "BBB-Index",
      "BBB-Non-Index"
    ],
    "Sectors": [
      "Financials-Index",
      "Energy-Index",
      "Information Technology-Index"
    ],
    "Clusters": [
      "0-Index",
      "2-Index",
      "2-Non-Index",
      "6-Index"
    ],
    "Signals": [
      "0-Index",
      "0-Non-Index",
      "1-Index",
      "1-Non-Index",
      "8-Index",
      "8-Non-Index",
      "9-Index",
      "9-Non-Index"
    ]
  },
  "1-3": {
    "view": "Snapshot",
    "bucket": "3_7",
    "group": "Signals",
    "metric": "Total Inquiry Count",
    "unit": null,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1000,
    "Ratings": [
      "A-Index",
      "A-Non-Index",
      "BBB-Index",
      "BBB-Non-Index"
    ],
    "Sectors": [
      "Financials-Index",
      "Energy-Index",
      "Information Technology-Index"
    ],
    "Clusters": [
      "0-Index",
      "2-Index",
      "2-Non-Index",
      "6-Index"
    ],
    "Signals": [
      "0-Index",
      "0-Non-Index",
      "1-Index",
      "1-Non-Index",
      "8-Index",
      "8-Non-Index",
      "9-Index",
      "9-Non-Index"
    ]
  },
    "Total Inquiry Count" : {
        "unit": null,
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 1000
    },
    "Total Inquiry Volume" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 1000000000
    },
    "Quoted Inquiry Count" : {
        "unit": null,
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 1000
    },
    "Quoted Inquiry Volume" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 1000000000
    },
    "Transaction Count" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 50
    },
    "Transaction Volume Gross" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : 0,
        "max" : 5000000
    },
    "Transaction Volume Net" : {
        "unit": "$",
        "min" : -1000000,
        "max" : 1000000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following method for merging the initial state and the setting from database:-

```
function mergeUserSetting (initialState, stateFromDatabase) {
  const result = {}
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(initialState)) {
    const type = Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1)
    if (type === 'Object') {
      result[key] = stateFromDatabase[key] ? mergeUserSetting(value, stateFromDatabase[key]) : value
    } else {
      result[key] = stateFromDatabase[key] ? stateFromDatabase[key] : value
    }
  }
  return result
}

export function panels (state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SETTINGS_LOADED:
      if (!action.payload || Object.keys(action.payload).length === 0) {
        return state;
      }
      return mergeUserSetting(state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```